# How to restrict iOS Keyboard app to only iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I'm designing a keyboard that takes advantage of the larger screen of iPhone 6 Plus (but on iPhone 6 it's usable to some extent too). My keyboard is basically useless on pre-4.7 inch devices (e.g. iPhone 5s and below) and for this reason I need to target only iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, and any future iPhones. Is this possible? If yes, how? If not, what would be a good workaround?

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible.  You will need to support all devices that can run iOS 8

Comment: @Paulw11 but the whole app is based on the extra real estate available on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. There *should* be a workaround in the logical sense.

Comment: I don't believe that your app will make it through App Store review if it doesn't support iPhone 4S/5/5S in some way.

Comment: @Paulw11 It technically can support, I mean, it will work as a regular keyboard, but I don't want to, as there's no meaning in it.

Comment: I don't think that is a choice you get to make (not wanting to I mean) - as you say it may not have any advantage, but you can't prevent it from running on a pre 6 device

Comment: @Paulw11 Well I'll just try to explain it in details, and add some "boilerplate" functionality just to support older devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62788/discussion-between-paulw11-and-can-poyrazoglu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit an app to the app store that exclusively runs on iPhone 6.  You must also support 5, 5c, 5s and 4s.  There is no workaround other than providing a version of your keyboard that works on all of these devices.